# PyQt, how can I connect button?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a login form and I want to connect the button to another window. So here is my code but when I run it, it shows the login window but after I clicked the button the next window only shows up for a moment. I tried multiple times after watching here and there but it didn't work out.

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setGeometry(750, 350, 400, 225)
          self.setWindowTitle('Login')

          #stuff right here

          self.tombol = QPushButton('Login', self)
          self.tombol.setGeometry(225, 150, 101, 23)
          self.tombol.clicked.connect(Main)
          self.show()

 class Main(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setGeometry(750, 350, 400, 150)
          self.setWindowTitle('Hasil Pilkada')

          #stuff right here too

          self.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simple: Main is created with a limited scope, so a moment later it will be eliminated, so the window is seen in a single moment.

The objective could be rewritten as: when the button is pressed then the other window must be shown, for the user it is indifferent if it is created before the window or not but only shown.

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.other_window = Main()

          self.setGeometry(750, 350, 400, 225)
          self.setWindowTitle('Login')

          #stuff right here

          self.tombol = QPushButton('Login', self)
          self.tombol.setGeometry(225, 150, 101, 23)
          self.tombol.clicked.connect(self.other_window.show)
          self.show()

 class Main(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setGeometry(750, 350, 400, 150)
          self.setWindowTitle('Hasil Pilkada')

          #stuff right here too

          # self.show()
```

Another way where if the window is created and shown:

```
class Login(QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()

          self.setGeometry(750, 350, 400, 225)
          self.setWindowTitle('Login')

          #stuff right here

          self.tombol = QPushButton('Login', self)
          self.tombol.setGeometry(225, 150, 101, 23)
          self.tombol.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)
          self.show()

    def handle_clicked(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "other_window"):
            self.other_window = Main()
        self.other_window.show()
```